# Good reference for logic behind emacs keybindings?

Tags: emacs

Is there a good resource that explains the logic/good practices behind Emacs keybinding schema (e.g. when to use C-x  vs. C-c ?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: <kbd>C-x</kbd> is usually for commands that are useful globally. While <kbd>C-c</kbd> is often for major-mode specific commands.

You can read the [Key Binding Conventions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html) to get some hints.

Or some other references:

1. [Emacs: Overview of Keybinding Design: M-x, C-x, C-c, C-M-](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_keybinding_overview.html)
2. [Are there any emacs key combinations reserved for custom commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144424/are-there-any-emacs-key-combinations-reserved-for-custom-commands/)
3. [Emacs: how to choose good custom key bindings?](https://superuser.com/questions/214295/emacs-how-to-choose-good-custom-key-bindings)