# How to determine whether command should be control or meta?

Tags: emacs

Is there a set of criteria to determine whether a command should be a `ctrl` keybinding or a `meta` keybinding?

For example, file handling commands seem to fall under `C-x` bindings. Cursor movements are a mix of `ctrl` and `meta`. I don't notice much of a pattern other than built-in bindings leaning towards `ctrl` which suggets `meta` may be somewhat reserved for user bindings.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of a fixed set of criteria to distinguish between commands bound to `Ctrl` or `Meta`. However, the Emacs Lisp manual has a section on [Key Binding Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html) that should be interesting to you.

Meta is not officially reserved for user-defined bindings:

> Sequences consisting of `C-c` and a letter (either upper or lower case) are reserved for users; they are the **only** sequences reserved for users, [...].

If you're asking because you want to set up custom key bindings for commands that don't have any by default, I suggest you also take a look at [Emacs: How to choose good custom key bindings?](https://superuser.com/q/214295/120085) and [Are there any emacs key combinations reserved for custom commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1144424/1199226)

Additionally, when binding keys be aware that

> A `<Control>`-modified alphabetical character is always considered case-insensitive: Emacs always treats `C-A` as `C-a`, `C-B` as `C-b`, and so forth. [...]
>
> For all other modifiers, you can make the modified alphabetical characters case-sensitive when you customize Emacs. For instance, you could make `M-a` and `M-A` run different commands.

... as described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifier-Keys.html).